# Swift - Double to String Precision Loss

Tags: string, swift, casting, double, precision

I'm trying to convert a double to a string in Swift and experiencing a significant loss in precision. Here's my code:

```
    var myDouble : Double = 23.00

    myDouble = myDouble / 100

    var myString : String = String(format: "%.20f", myDouble)

    println(myString)
```

**expected result:** 0.23000000000000000000

**actual result:** 0.23000000000000000999

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: That is to be expected! `Double` is a *binary* floating point number and ***cannot*** represent the number 0.23 exactly.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that was very helpful. 

To expand further, using

         println(myDouble)

gives the expected output of 0.23. I don't understand why the additional 999's are being added when the pointer is referencing 0.23.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: `println()` *truncates* the output at 6 decimals, therefore it *seems* that `myDouble` is exactly 0.23. But it isn't ...